# Columns are ignored when no matching row found in LEFT JOIN while using CASE WHEN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to fetch a collection report of bills paid for a hospital. There's a table where advance amount paid by patients are recoreded. Not all patients pay advance.

This is the query I use now

```
"SELECT SUM(
    CASE 
    WHEN bill_type = 3 THEN b.payable_amount + w.balance
    ELSE 0
 END) AS 'amount'

 FROM bills b 
    LEFT JOIN ip_patients ip on ip.id = b.ip_id
    LEFT JOIN advance w on w.id = (SELECT x.id FROM advance x WHERE x.ip_id = ip.id ORDER BY x.created_at DESC  LIMIT 1)
    WHERE b.doctor_id = '$d->id' AND CAST(b.created_at AS DATE) >= '$date1' AND CAST(b.created_at AS DATE) <= '$date2' AND b.is_cancelled = 0 AND b.is_deleted = 0"
```

If a patient didn't pay the advance, no row is inserted in `advance` table. What happens with the above query is that, when there's no row for a patient in advance table, his payment is totally ignored (ie, the value in `bills` table is not added to the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a null to a not null the result is null. for example

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> set @a = null;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> set @b = 100;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select @a+@b amt;
+------+
| amt  |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And you can use ifnull to deal with this

```
set @a = null;
set @b = 100;

select ifnull(@a,0) + ifnull(@b,0) amt;

+-----+
| amt |
+-----+
| 100 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```